# Summing a dataframe and keeping row labels

Tags: python, pandas

I am just wondering if it's possible to sum a dataframe showing a total value at the end of each column while keeping the label string description in the zero column (like you would in Excel)?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Summing a column is as easy as `Dataframe_Name['COLUMN_NAME'].sum()` you can review it [In the Documentation Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

You can also do `Dataframe_Name.sum()` and it will return the sums for each column